# Import Data different column length

Tags: list-manipulation, import

Lets assume, i have this data.txt file.

```
s1/km  t1/h   s2/km    t2/h
20     1      40       1

40     2      80       2

60     3
```

I define myself a function for processing

```
deleteRows[expr_] := Replace[expr, x_List :> DeleteCases[x, {}], {0, Infinity}]
```

Then import the file:

```
data = deleteRows@Import["data.txt", "Table"][[2 ;;]]
```

Everythings works fine till now. But if I want to select the 3rd column it breaks.

```
data[[All, 3]]
```

How do I deal with such situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
dataraw = Import["data.txt", "Table", 
  "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True, "HeaderLines" -> 1]
```

> `{{20, 1, 40, 1}, {40, 2, 80, 2}, {60, 3}}`

Then for example:

```
data = PadRight[dataraw, {Automatic, Automatic}, "NA"]
```

> `{{20, 1, 40, 1}, {40, 2, 80, 2}, {60, 3, "NA", "NA"}}`

Finally,

```
data[[All, 3]]
```

> `{40, 80, "NA"}`

Comment: This is great! I am going to modify my answer to just have the R commands.

Comment: Thank you very much. There remain only some questions: PadRight[dataraw, Automatic, "NA"] works as well. Why do you make a list of the Automatic option?

Comment: Does one have to use "NA"? Are there some list handling built in functions in mathematica that treat "NA" in a special way? Or could one use also "any string"? At least for ListPlot[] the "any string" works. Because of the answer by @AntonAntonov I tried PadRight[dataraw, Automatic, Missing[]] which also works and to me this seems the cleanest solution, or whats the purpose of Missing[]?

Comment: `Missing[__]` has documentation and handling in Mathematica. See the  function pages for `Missing`, `DeleteMissing`, `MissingQ`.

Comment: @mcocdawc Yes, [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) is certainly the way to go with mma versions >=10, for the reasons you say (see the Details section of the doc). And yes, one `Automatic` is sufficient here (the double `{Automatic, Automatic}` just reminds that you pad a 2d array (but this is useless of course here to pad with new lines containing `Missing` data.

Answer (score 3):

**Using R/RLink**

Since this scenario happens fairly often when doing data analysis here is a solution using R (through RLink):

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]

rres = REvaluate[
  "read.table( file = \"./data.txt\", quote = \"\", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)"]

(* RDataFrame[RNames["s1.km", "t1.h", "s2.km", "t2.h"], 
 RData[{20, 40, 60}, {1, 2, 3}, {40, 80, Missing[]}, {1, 2, 
   Missing[]}], RRowNames[1, 2, 3]] *)

data = Transpose[ List @@ rres[[2]] ];
data[[All, 3]]

(* {40, 80, Missing[]} *)
```

Note the parallels with the solution by SquareOne.

Comment: Shouldn't the data be transposed ?

Comment: @SquareOne Yes, thank you! I forgot that data frames in R are column-wise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but since I am not familiar with RLink the answer by SquareOne is of better use for me.

Comment: @mcocdawc No problem! The solution of SqureOne was also unknown to me -- I use/used a different, less convenient approach. (It was in the first version of my post.) I kept the R/RLink solution because I have to execute that command often when using R and because it is analogous to using Import with the proposed options.